# Most efficient way to cache images in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, caching

I am developing a Laravel application in which I need to display images from Instagram's CDN and thought it would be a good idea to cache these instead of constantly having to query the CDN.

I found [Intervention Image Cache](https://github.com/Intervention/imagecache) as the only option for my requirements. I wrote a simple route that involved passing part of the CDN url and then calling a controller to cache the image. I must mention I'm using FileSystem storage as the cache driver.

`routes/web.php`

```php
Route::get('/img/{code}/', 'PostController@setImageCached');
```

`app/Http/Controllers/PostController.php`

```php
public function setImageCached($code) {
        $cdn_image = $this->getImage($code);
        $img = Image::cache(function($img) use($cdn_image){
            return $img->make($cdn_image);
        }, 10);
        return Response::make($img, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg'));
    }
```

And whilst it works, it's painfully slow, almost three times slower than actually getting the image directly from the CDN, so either I'm using the library wrong or it's not caching the images.

Is there a better approach to caching images from a CDN so that my application does not have to constantly query Instagram's CDN?

Comment: Try cache images via nginx or apache.

Comment: What does `getImage` return?

Comment: Use php-fpm. Hope it is help. My all project working on php-fpm.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the built-in Laravel caching mechanism. Not sure how the library you're using works so this may be a more reliable approach.

```php
public function setImageCached($code) {
        $cdn_image = $this->getImage($code);
        $img = Cache::remember('image_'.$cdn_image, 10, function () use ($cdn_image) {  
           return file_get_contents($cdn_image);
        });
        return Response::make($img, 200, array('Content-Type' => 'image/jpeg'));
    }
```

Comment: Does the same code always generate the same image url?

Comment: My question is more about `$cdn_image = $this->getImage($code)` will the same `$code` value always result in the same `$cdn_image` value?

Comment: `Cache::remember` is meant to either return the image from the cache if it's present or run the function to retrieve the image if it's not. Whether or not the image is present is determined by the cache key in this case `'image_'.$cdn_image`